# Почему wait/notify/notifyAll методы определены в классе Object, а не в классе Thread?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Почему `wait/notify/notifyAll` методы определены в классе `Object`, а не в классе `Thread`?

Comment: очевидно для того, чтобы можно было вешать ожидание на любой объект, нет?

Comment: Thread имеет метод sleep, остальное неактуально для статического метода.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

На самом деле интересный вопрос.

В java объекты могут выступать в роли mutex'ов, т.е. участвовать в процессе разграничения доступа к ресурсам между различными потоками. С помощью `synchronized` блока и методов `wait`, `notify`, `notifyAll`.

Соответственно, доступ к этому объекту должен быть для всех потоков, желающих получить монопольное право на ресурс. Отсюда и вытекает ответ на ваш вопрос - почему эти методы не находятся в классе `Thread`. Если бы это было так, другим потокам пришлось бы хранить информацию о других потоках (ожидающих доступ к ресурсу) и самостоятельно, заниматься их пробуждением, в момент освобождения ресурса, что согласитесь не очень удобно

Answer (score 5):

Потому что эти методы относятся, непосредственно, к объекту. Таким образом можно выполнять блокировку на любом объекте Java, заставляя очередь потоков бороться за захват монитора текущего объекта.